# Как установить связь между элементами двух массивов, чтобы после перемешивания элементов первого массива связь не терялась

Tags: java, android, массивы

Есть массив вопросов:

```
String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
```

Есть массив ответов на эти вопросы:

```
String[]answers= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
```

Изначально первый вопрос в массиве вопросов соответствует первому ответу в массиве ответов. В процессе игры пользователь должен ответить на вопрос и его ответ должен сравниваться с ответом из массива ответов, в результате чего либо прибавляется балл, либо нет. Ответы из массива нигде не выводятся. Отвечать на вопросы можно многократно с целью улучшения результата.

Но, чтобы исключить момент механического запоминания ответов по очередности их появления (*если вопросы будут все время показывать в одном и том же порядке*), вопросы перед стартом перемешиваются с помощью специального метода.

Проблема в том, как теперь указать программе, какой из ответов соответствует какому из вопросов в перемешанном массиве вопросов? Можно ли в андроид изначально связать элементы из одного массива с соответствующим им элементам из другого массива, чтобы после перемешивания первого массива, программа сохраняла связь между элементом из первого массива и элементом из второго массива?

Быть может, эту задачу может решить каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Сделайте *правильно* - создайте объектную модель, в которой у объекта Вопрос будет ссылка на объект Ответ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вам надо создать модель данных, содержащую и вопрос и ответ. После этого список этих моделей можно мешать как угодно без потери связности.

```
public class QAModel
{
    String q;
    String a;

    QAModel(String q, String a)
    {
         this.q=q;
         this.a=a;
    }

    public String getQ(){return q;}

    public String getA(){return a;}
}
```

Теперь вы можете создавать вашу модель из ваших данных:

```
String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
String[] answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
ArrayList<QAModel> models=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< questions.lenght; i++)
{
    models.add(new QAModel(questions[i], answers[i]));
}
```

Теперь вы можете сортировать вопросы, не теряя связь с ответами.

Comment: Честно говоря, решила свой вопрос совершенно другим способом, т.к. Ваш для меня пока сложен для понимания. И тем не менее, внедрить Ваш способ у меня не получилось. Тут, возможно, дело в том,что я вывожу вопросы не с помощью ArrayList. У меня есть некое поле textView, в которое в текстовом виде передаются вопросы (точнее - примеры). Рядом с ним - поле edittext и кнопка "Далее". Когда пользователь ответил на вопрос, его ответ сравнивается с ответом из массива ответов, он нажимает кнопку Далее, и в поле с вопросами передается текст со следующим вопросом из массива.

Comment: @VolhaGomel, способ представления данных не должен сильо влиять на способ их использования. Вместо обращения к массивам вашим вы теперь можете обращаться к полям элементов списка как-то так: `textView.setText(models.get(numberOfCurrentQuestionn).getQ());`. Соответственно получить ответ можно так: `String answer = models.get(numberOfCurrentQuestionn).getA();`

Answer (score 6):

Ну на самом деле напрашиваются сразу 2 варианта решения:

1 - создать класс `Quiz` с полями `question` и `answer`. Создать список, который будет содержать экземпляры данного класса с вопросом и ответом. Дальше можете перемешивать как хотите данный список.

2 - Создать TreeMap и заполнить ее данными, в качестве ключа вопрос, в качестве значения - ответ.

**ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ ПРЕДПОЧТИТЕЛЬНЕЕ :)**